# Wrong vertical Box alignment

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to align some tables in my application window. In the following window, all of 3 tables must fill horizontally the application window area. Instead 2 of 3 tables take exactly 50% of width of application window.

`JFrame.getContentPane()` --> `JTabbedPane` --> `pnlInvoices = Box.createVerticalBox()` --> components with wrong alignment.

Components with wrong alignment are a `JSplitPane`, a `JTableHeader` and a `JTable`. The code which creates that, are the following:

```
JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
        new JScrollPane(tblInvoices),
        new JScrollPane(tblItems));
sp.setDividerSize(3);
sp.setDividerLocation(75);
Box pnlInvoices = Box.createVerticalBox();
pnlInvoices.add(sp);
JTable tblReport = PropertiesTableModel.createTable(irtm);
pnlInvoices.add(tblReport.getTableHeader());    // JTable must be inside JScrollPane, or else header must be added manually
pnlInvoices.add(tblReport);
//...
JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
//...
tabs.addTab("Τιμολόγια", pnlInvoices);
//...
getContentPane().add(tabs);
```

[image: The result in application window]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with a hack. But I don't understand why.

```
    JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
            new JScrollPane(tblInvoices),
            new JScrollPane(tblItems));
    sp.setDividerSize(3);
    sp.setDividerLocation(75);
    Box pnl = Box.createHorizontalBox();        // Hack
    pnl.add(sp);
    Box pnlInvoices = Box.createVerticalBox();
    pnlInvoices.add(pnl);
    JTable tblReport = PropertiesTableModel.createTable(irtm);
    pnlInvoices.add(tblReport.getTableHeader());
    pnlInvoices.add(tblReport);
```